# Shortcut for running entire test class while in test method in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, attempting to use a run shortcut such as `Control + Shift + R` while the cursor is in a test method results in just running the specific test under the cursor. However, often, I'll want to run the entire test class.

I get around this by jumping my cursor outside of the test method and then hitting the shortcut to run the class, but I was curious if there's a way to do this more directly rather than jumping back and forth?

I thought the `RunClass` action would do this, but it seems to only run the method enclosing the cursor.

Comment: Once you've run the tests in the entire class once, there will be a (temporary) run configuration. Then when you hit `Alt + Shift + F10` you should get a popup where you can select a run configuration and choose the run configuration that runs all tests in the class.